# Primefaces Datatable Selection Large Dataset

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

My application is using:
WildFly 8.2
Mojarra 2.2.8-jbossorg-1 (the one that comes with WildFly).
Primefaces 5.2
JDK8

There's a page where I need to load many files (around 12k) and then show their names to the user so he/she can choose which ones they want to pick up.

And I'm able to show my datatable with the files as expected.
The problem starts when I select more than 1k rows and try to go to the next page of the datatable.
It gets incredibly slow.

I use multiple selection with checkboxes, and from what I saw every time I change the page it sends every checkbox as a parameter from the request.
I really have no idea of how to solve this. Hope someone might help with any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Try the PF partial submit functionality… in combination with a process attribute on the ajaxevents with a value of @this

Comment: Hi kukeltje, thank you for answering me [here and on StackOverflow =) ], however that didn't solve it.

I think there's something to do with fact that primefaces need to compare both list on every page to check whick rows are selected.

So, instead of using the common selection I created a DTO with a boolean column, this way it worked.

Thank you again.

=)